# CSRF & CORS issue with angularjs and spring security

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, csrf

Struggling for quite some time. I am having Angular.js at front with Java/J2EE (RESTFul) at the backend with Spring security (Enabled Cors-filter). Spring security works perfectly fine except when I try to enable csrf protection. Below is my code I tried for csrf:

My CSRF filter

```
    public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
            .getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
        String token = csrf.getToken();
        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

Security configuration has below code:

```
        @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authSuccess)
                .failureHandler(authFailure)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, HeaderWriterFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
            //.csrf().disable();
}

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

Had to modify CORS filter to add X-XSRF-TOKEN header name inside Access-Control-Allow-Headers as initially it was giving this error.

```
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-XSRF-TOKEN, x-requested-with, Content-Type");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

My angular js code:

```
                $scope.login = function () {
            $http.post("http://localhost:9090/cynosureserver/login", "username=" + $scope.user.name +
                    "&password=" + $scope.user.password, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')


                }
                    }).then(function (data) {
                alert("login successful" + JSON.stringify(data));
            }, function (err) {
                alert("error logging in" + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        };
```

I have debug points set up. After login form it goes to Csrf filter. But never hit my "CustomUserDetailsService". The problem is I always get 403 response saying:

HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?

If I make a simple Get request it is successful and also "XSRF-TOKEN" cookie is received inside Response Header.

But for my post method I am unable to proceed. 
I am seeing below:

```
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:[::1]:9090
```

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-XSRF-TOKEN, x-requested-with, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
.... 
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=5DE6DB8B5E31DC77DC4ED28600445615; Path=/cynosureserver/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
...
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:9090
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
X-XSRF-TOKEN:7c2057b5-0f1a-4dc1-bab4-c8f000a2ae2d
```

Form Data

```
username:manisha
password:123456
```

I tried many different combinations but nothing seems to work, Please help me - what am I missing ? I am totally clueless here. Sorry for lengthy post.

Comment: I tried many different ways. One way was to combine front UI server and backend server and try to see if this is due to CORS filter. After running both on one server did the magic. As mentioned in the spring docs, I don't need to do anything at front end. My cookie gets set properly and is send back properly. But then problem remains if I have 2 separate servers. It seems even though I am seeing Set-Cookie inside request header, does not get set. Any thoughts on this please?